# Get current extent of OpenLayers map in polygon coordinates

Tags: openlayers

How can I get current extent of OpenLayers map in polygon coordinates?

I have tried this way:

```
export function getExtent(map: MapOl, from = 'EPSG:3857', to = 'EPSG:4326') {
  return transformExtent(map.getView().calculateExtent(), from, to);
}
```

As result I got array:

```
[
    37.45404276148633,
    55.714778532256986,
    37.78603586451367,
    55.78376067597284
]
```

But I need to get array of array coordinates:

```
[[x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [xclose, yclose]]
```

Comment: You can create a polygon geometry from an extent https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.fromExtent

Comment: From what? Could you share an example? I dont have features. I just need to get polygon extention of map view

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-3hh2m3?file=/main.js

Comment: Thank you a lot, it is easy :) How to convert meters to 4326? to get coordinates of polygon in 4326?

Comment: I have tried from   'EPSG:3857' to
      'EPSG:4326'

Comment: The example is converting to EPSG:4326.  The lon/lat values will be fractional, and some of the longitudes may be wrapped so outside the -180/+180 range.

Comment: Could you share an example? I just need to convet in EPSG:4326 from meteres I assume.

Comment: So, when I get polygon of map extent I got it in meters? Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var extend = [
    37.45404276148633,
    55.714778532256986,
    37.78603586451367,
    55.78376067597284
]
```

if data showing like that you just need to get specific as you needed
`[[x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [xclose, yclose]]`

my solution will be like bellow, and your data extend actually was on ESPG:4326

```
var newExtend = [
[extend[0], extend[1]],
[extend[3], extend[1]],
[extend[3], extend[4]],
[extend[0], extend[4]],
[extend[0], extend[1]]
]
```